# Delay code execution while running program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

What is the best way to delay code execution in an application while the program is still running?

I've tried this method:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()
```

But the application does not display until the `Sleep()` has been executed and I am unsure of alternatives.

Comment: Tidied up language and formatting. More background information, explaining the context, may be helpful to help get constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Boolean).Run(Function() As Boolean
                                                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
                                                                Return True
                                                            End Function)

        Dim ret = t.Result
```

You need to offload this to another thread, if you call sleep on the current thread then everything including the UI is going to wait until sleep has finished. There are multiple ways to achieve this including the example above.